# Typo3 tt_news add Parameter to URL

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

how can i read out the current id from tt_news and add this as a parameter to the url

a small review of my TYPOSCRIPT

```
2 = TMENU
2 {
wrap = <ul class="naviMainLevel2"> | </ul>
NO {
wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
}
ACT = 1
ACT {
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"> | </li>
#get current tt_news id add it to the menu
additionalParams.data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
additionalParams.intval = 1
additionalParams.wrap = &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=|
#returns only &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=0
#maybe is it possible with RECORDS tt_news.mbl_newsevent, to get the id? 
}
CUR = 1
CUR < .ACT
}
```

url should then look like this: www.example.com/news/news-tech?&tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=55

Updated:

i think this is a problem with the extension mbl_newsevent it shows only news with an registration option and a button with the current tt_news id...generated with this TS:

```
plugin.tt_news.mbl_newsevent {
    registrationLink_typolink {
            title.data = LLL:EXT:mbl_newsevent/locallang.xml:registerLinkLabel
            parameter = {$powermail.plugin.pid}
            parameter.override.field = tx_mblnewsevent_regurl
            additionalParams.field = uid
            additionalParams.intval = 1
            additionalParams.wrap = &tx_powermail_pi1[eventUid]=|
                #this returns the correct tt_news id for the button
        }  
}
```

i need the same way for my url....

Comment: I didn't get your problem. Why do you need to add this parameter to current url, before you click on a link? Just imagine a sitution, when you have a list of news items with their "Register" links, where each link has it's own different `eventUid` - what shouold be in current URL then?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi i updated my problem for better understanding...i only want know how can i get the current id of tt_news...additionalParams = {GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news} ### NEWS-ID as GET should not work or i do something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to correct your code in a following way:

```
2 = TMENU
2 {
  wrap = <ul class="naviMainLevel2"> | </ul>
  NO {
   wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
  }
  ACT = 1
  ACT {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"> | </li>

    #parameter.override.field = tt_news_id ||uid
    # ^ you don't need this line, becasue you still need 
    # the current page id in url and it shouldn't be overriden
    # by some other param

    # next you need to get current tt_news uid from GET
    # as you mentioned in your comment
    additionalParams.data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
    additionalParams.intval = 1
    additionalParams.wrap = &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=|
  }
  CUR = 1
  CUR < .ACT
}
```

Comment: thx but it returns &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=0 :( the correct id would be 99...see updated post on top

Comment: @Jim are you trying to get tt_news uid in your `TMENU` or in `plugin.tt_news.mbl_newsevent`?